# Sometimes when modifying properties in a foreach loop, the changes do not remain

Tags: c#, linq

Sometimes when looping through an Enumerable returned by LINQ and modifying a property of the elements in it, the changes are lost outside of the foreach loop. I have so far only noticed it when the enumerable is created with .Select(), and then only if I am creating a new object in the Select.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var collection1 = new List<TestClass>();
            collection1.Add(new TestClass() { Property = "initial" });
            collection1.Add(new TestClass() { Property = "initial" });
            var collection2 = new List<TestClass>();
            collection2.Add(new TestClass() { Property = "initial" });
            collection2.Add(new TestClass() { Property = "initial" });

            var enumerable1 = collection1.Select(x => x);

            var enumerable2 = collection2.Select(x => new TestClass() { Property = x.Property });

            foreach(var element in enumerable1)
            {
                element.Property = "new";
            }
            Console.WriteLine(enumerable1.First().Property); //outputs "new"

            foreach (var element in enumerable2)
            {
                element.Property = "new";
            }
            Console.WriteLine(enumerable2.First().Property); //outputs "initial"
        }
    }

    class TestClass
    {
        public string Property;
    }
}
```

Is this some sort of bug, or am I doing something I shouldn't be?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967085/uning-linq-to-change-values-in-collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that here:

```
foreach (var element in enumerable2)
{
    element.Property = "new";
}
```

you are evaluating the expression:

```
collection2.Select(x => new TestClass() { Property = x.Property })
```

Then with this: `enumerable2.First().Property`, you are evaluating the expression again. Unless you call `ToList()` on your expression, you re-evaluate the expression again. What you have is functionally equivalent to:

```
foreach (var element in collection2.Select(x => new TestClass() { Property = x.Property }))
{
    element.Property = "new";
}
Console.WriteLine(collection2.Select(x => new TestClass() { Property = x.Property }).First().Property)
```

See what is going on? To fix this, call a `ToList()` on your declaration of `enumerable2`:

```
var enumerable2 = collection2.Select(x => new TestClass() { Property = x.Property }).ToList()
```

Comment: why this is not happening in first foreach loop where enumerable1 was used.

Comment: with the first `foreach` loop you are modifying the elements in `collection1` while with the second, you are modifying the new element created in the `Select` function which gets recreated every time it is evaluated